# npm search takes a long time

Tags: npm

In general npm search behaves strange, it takes a very long time, and it varies in order and time, from time to time.

The first time I wrote

```
$ npm search jquery
```

it took more than two minutes. Subsequent searches have taken around 30 seconds. Sometimes I get the matches before the http request, sometimes the other way around:

**Matching results first**

```
$ npm search jquery.appendgrid
NAME               DESCRIPTION                                         AUTHOR      DATE              VERSION KEYWORDS
jquery.appendgrid  appendGrid - The dynamic table input jQuery plugin  =hkalbertl  2014-12-21 08:09  1.5.1  jquery-plugin ui header-detail master-d
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1419625615355
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1419625615355
```

**Matching results last**

```
$ npm search jquery.appendgrid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1419625643062
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1419625643062
NAME               DESCRIPTION                                         AUTHOR      DATE              VERSION KEYWORDS
jquery.appendgrid  appendGrid - The dynamic table input jQuery plugin  =hkalbertl  2014-12-21 08:09  1.5.1  jquery-plugin ui header-detail master-d
```

In either case it takes around thirty seconds. Since it takes less than the initial two minutes I guess something has been cached, but it still makes a http request, and it still takes surprisingly long. It's not the time between the first http line and the second, that only takes 1-2 seconds. But there is a lot of waiting time both before and after.

What is going on, and can I speed it up?

Comment: The 'internet' is busy? Seriously, how busy is the website? how often are you doing this? and 'why'?

Comment: I read your comment as if I'm doing something really stupid, let me know if that's the case. I read a tutorial, it said that I could search for packages in npm by doing `npm search`, so that's what I do. Maybe I'm not supposed to use it this way? If the search functionality is not for looking for packages, then what is it for?

Comment: And I don't understand what you mean by "The 'internet' is busy?". Is it even a question? Why is 'internet' in quotes? This has nothing to do with my internet connection, that's all I know.

Comment: I made no assumptions as to your skill level. Sorry for the confusion with the 'internet' part of the comment - just ignore it. Was curious as to how often you are searching for stuff using 'npm' is all. My understanding, which may be faulty, is that you use 'npm' when installing 'new' stuff. So the few minutes it takes would not be such an issue as it doesn't happen that often.

Comment: A ok :) I am reading this tutorial, http://tech.pro/tutorial/1190/package-managers-an-introductory-guide-for-the-uninitiated-front-end-developer, just trying to learn NPM and Bower. I did the `npm search` as they write it, and it behaves strange (I think). So I suspect that I'm either using it wrong, or NPM is set up wrong. But perhaps it takes 30 seconds for everyone, which just seems silly to me.

Comment: t has to do a lot of on your local server as regards checking dependencies as well as with the server and ensure everything matches up. It is not a 'trivial' task. And, yes, it takes a while here as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A year ago, when that tutorial was written, `npm` had fewer published packages.  Currently there are over 100,000.  In order to do a `npm search`, `npm` downloads a JSON file describing all of the packages, crudely indexes it, and then searches over all the package descriptions.

The result is that `npm search` as a local command is essentially broken right now -- it completes, but very slowly, and it creates an alarmingly large file to do so (60MB).

The suggested workaround for now is to use the online search tool at https://www.npmjs.com/

Comment: Great complete answer :)

Comment: ...and uses a lot of memory while searching.  One of my environments is a small VM with 256MB of memory, and npm search won't complete on it (it starts thrashing and never finishes).

Comment: I did an accidental 'npm search' with no package name and it said it was updating the local cache for a first time run. So I assumed it would end fairly quickly. *My* problem is its still running 45 minutes later, is using up over 1GB of swap, and about 1.5GB of RAM. I haven't Ctl-C'd it yet because I was unsure if I would fundamentally break something if it didn't complete. Glad I went searching. I know not to use this aspect of the tool in the future.

Comment: Ctrl-C is a safe way to interrupt it.

Comment: Well.  At least now I now not to search.  Though it surprises me this hasn't been rewritten (is npm in active development?) or eclipsed by something that does it better (the alarming proliferation of other tools is exactly the problem here -- it seems like someone would have produced *this* one).

I suppose doing this myself, or finding out why I shouldn't, might be a good way to start getting involved.

Comment: @JonCarter - npm is under active development, but for the past year (at least?) they have been focusing on issues with correctness and speed.  npm@3 is almost a ground-up rewrite of the package installation pipeline, and removes several classes of race conditions.  Since the online search exists as a valid workaround, the search rewrite has been off the stove completely (not merely back-burnered).

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose.  You've got to prioritize, and it look like this will hopefully be fixed when npm3 is complete.

Comment: The online search isn't really a solution if you want to search programmatically. Or is there a way to get machine-readable results? My particular use case is that I want to check what the latest version of a package is...

Answer (score 1):

The npm repo should NOT be slow. Some people are saying here that it has over 100.000 packages... It actually has more than 165.000 but even this number is really small for any database. I believe they use CouchDB, which is very fast.
In any case, if you don't get the results that you want you can always use other alternative search sites like:

- http://search.node.modules.by.locoticket.com  (this is the best by far)
- http://nipstr.com/

Comment: It's not that the `npm` repo itself is slow; it's that the local search consists of 

1) downloading a snapshot of the repo
 2) parsing that >80MB JSON file with the builtin parser (non-streaming)3) searching it

That's what's slow.  The npm repository is fast, as you can see when installing packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen too, I suspect npm updates a locally cached package list.  The long delay could be fetching the repo data.

Just now my first search took 35 seconds (a little cpu, a long wait, then 10 seconds of solid cpu).  Subsequent searches are taking 11 seconds, with 97% cpu utilization.

Edit: 10 sec cpu on an AMD 3.6 GHz Phenom II, adjust for your hardware accordingly.

Comment: Interesting. For comparison `bower search jquery` takes 2-3 seconds on my computer.